# Using only Posix features, what is the most efficient way to grow a file to X bytes large?

Tags: c, linux, unix, posix

My Posix C program needs to grow a file to X bytes large - typically 128MB or 256MB.

The current approach is to initialise a memory buffer of 16MB and repeatedly write the buffer into the opened file using `fwrite`.

Is there a more efficient approach?

Comment: Do you actually need to fill that space or are you only interested in the directory entry?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams the space would need to be filled by 0s.

Comment: Would they only need to read as 0, or would you need actual 0s on the hard drive?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams the latter.

Comment: What is the reason to do so? Note that some advanced filesystems may map multiple blocks to one, if the contents is the same. (e.g. `btrfs` uses `copy-on-write` mechanism for files)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [ftruncate](http://linux.die.net/man/2/ftruncate) system call.

Answer (score 3):

You can quickly fill a file with all zeros by seeking to an offset and writing a byte there. The contents of the file before that offset will be filled with zeros if the file was not that large already.

On Linux this will create a [sparse file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file). The file will *appear* be of size 256MB but it will actually use very little space on disk.

Answer (score 2):

Use [ftruncate](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/ftruncate.html) , despite its name it can be used to extend files too. It might be slightly less portable compared to your current method as posix does not require ftruncate to be able to extend a file (but  [XSI](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap03.html#tag_03_439) does)

Answer (score 0):

Note about sparse files - which all of the answers create for you

code:

```
// ft.c
int main()
{
   FILE*fp=fopen("sparse", "w");
   ftruncate(fileno(fp), 2147483647UL);
   fclose(fp);
   return 0;
}
```

show the disk before and after running ./ft:

```
me@mycomputer ~> gcc ft.c -o ft
me@mycomputer ~> du -sh .
 368M .
me@mycomputer ~> df -h .
Filesystem             Size   Used  Available Capacity  Mounted on
/                       98G   8.3G        89G     9%    /
me@mycomputer ~> ./ft
me@mycomputer ~> df -h .
Filesystem             Size   Used  Available Capacity  Mounted on
/                       98G   8.3G        89G     9%    /
me@mycomputer ~> du -sh .
 368M .
me@mycomputer ~> ls -l sparse
-rw-r--r--   1 me     other    2147483647 Dec 10 12:55 sparse
```

Now we back up sparse:

```
me@mycomputer ~> tar cvf /tmp/my.tar.tar ./sparse
a ./sparse 2097152K
```

Next we restore sparse from the backup:

```
me@mycomputer ~> tar xf /tmp/my.tar.tar .
me@mycomputer ~> du -sh .
 2.4G .
me@mycomputer ~> df -h .
Filesystem             Size   Used  Available Capacity  Mounted on
/                       98G    10G        87G    11%    /
```

Voila - we gained 2GB.  Sparse files are a great way to create a sort of future negative payback - a possible disk full error.  The above example is on the system disk - once the system disk is 100% full the system has all kinds of nasty problems.

This is because restoring files (months later maybe) inflates sparse files on disk to their "real" size. And you forgot about them in the meantime.

Seriously consider not creating these things in the first place, there usually are no requirements to do it.